# Oracle constraint - compare two string like two times

Tags: oracle, constraints, string-comparison, create-table

I would like to create table witj constrain which compare two varchar2(8 char) columns as time.
Is it possible ?

I've made somethink like this, but it doesn't work :(

`CONSTRAINT "my_constraint" CHECK (to_number(to_char(to_date(window_stop, 'hh24:mi:ss'), 'sssss')) > to_number(to_char(to_date(window_start, 'hh24:mi:ss'), 'sssss'))) ENABLE`

Thx for all help.
Paul.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are you getting an error? The wrong behavior?

Comment: that is a very bad idea. use always date fields to store dates. A time is basically a date formatted as hh:mi:ss or hh24:mi:ss.

Comment: are you getting `ORA-02436?  ??

Comment: If the values are all HH24:MI:SS with leading zeros, can't you just compare them as strings? Also, is the 'stop' always on the same day as the 'start'? If it can cross midnight then this constraint won't be right anyway.

Comment: yes, I have ORA-02436

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraint will get "ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint" because if you don't provide the date elements then `to_date()` defaults to the first day of the current month; therefore the result of evaluating the constraint check could change after the data is inserted, which isn't allowed. It can't actually change in this specific case, but a general rule is being applied, causing the error.

You could use a nominal fixed date instead:

```
CONSTRAINT "my_constraint"
  CHECK (
      to_number(to_char(to_date('2000-01-01 ' || window_stop, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), 'sssss'))
    > to_number(to_char(to_date('2000-01-01 ' || window_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), 'sssss'))
  ) ENABLE
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e753bd2c70352e590d3e18b6547783f)

There isn't much point converting to a number though, just compare the dates:

```
CONSTRAINT "my_constraint"
  CHECK (
      to_date('2000-01-01 ' || window_stop, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
    > to_date('2000-01-01 ' || window_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
  ) ENABLE
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=917e9e82fa7c391f673605c62698dd71)

Or - if you are confident that values are always going to be valid times and will have leading zeros - just compare the strings:

```
CONSTRAINT "my_constraint" CHECK (window_stop > window_start) ENABLE
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d9849f2bcd542276b4c84c747268fafb)

You could also store the times as nominal dates, or as number of seconds past midnight, or as an interval, which would make it easier to prevent completely invalid values being used (e.g. '99:00:00'). But you may have a real date you can use instead - depends if these are tied to real dates, or e.g. shift patterns, or similar - which would allow you to handle windows crossing midnight. (What you should *not* do is store a related date and time as separate fields, but no indication that is what you are doing here.)

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it is always a very bad idea to use varchar2 for date fields. Let me show you how your constraint is so easy when the fields are dates

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 date , c2 date ) ;

Table created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ;

Session altered.

SQL> insert into t values ( to_date('11.08.2020 14:00:00') , to_date('11.08.2020 14:10:00') ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t ;

C1                  C2
------------------- -------------------
11.08.2020 14:00:00 11.08.2020 14:10:00

SQL> select ( c2 - c1 ) * 24 * 60 * 60 from t ;

(C2-C1)*24*60*60
----------------
             600
```

Now, let's add the constraint

```
SQL> alter table t add constraint chk_test check ( c2 > c1 ) ;

Table altered.

SQL> insert into t values ( to_date('11.08.2020 14:11:00') , to_date('11.08.2020 14:10:00') ) ;
insert into t values ( to_date('11.08.2020 14:11:00') , to_date('11.08.2020 14:10:00') )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SYS.CHK_TEST) violated
```

You want to store times, which are dates, and you want to compare that the window_stop is greater than the window_start. Instead of making such complicated conversions, just store the fields as dates. Despite the fact that is the properly data type for the data you want to store, the constraint will work much more better.

Comment: Thx Roberto, but columns in my table are varchar2 (8 Char), and time is inserted as string, eg. time 12:34:55 in may table is 123455.